# Makefile says that variable is empty but it's not

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to create makefile with following content:

```
$(CXX)=g++
$(SRC)=../src
$(INCL)=../include
all: cpu ram temperature swap statusshooter
    $(CXX) main.cpp cpu.o ram.o temperature.o swap.o statusshooter.o -o main.o -I$(INCL) -Ofast -Wall -lyaml-cpp -lglog -lpqxx -lpq
cpu:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC)/CCpu.cpp -o cpu.o -Ofast -Wall 
ram:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC)/CRam.cpp -o ram.o -Ofast -Wall 
temperature:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC)/CTemperature.cpp -o temperature.o -Ofast -Wall
swap:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC)/CSwap.cpp -o swap.o -Ofast -Wall  
statusshooter:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC)/CStatusShooter.cpp -o statusshooter.o -Ofast -Wall
```

Executing that makefile with:
`make CXX=g++-4.7` throws following error:

```
makefile:2: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax `$(CXX)` is for evaluating a make variable, not assigning to it.  You want

```
CXX  = g++
SRC  = ../src
INCL = ../include

[...]
```

Comment: @OverKiller What worked "with [your] command" exactly? Do you mean you ran `make $(CXX)=g++4.7`? Because that shouldn't have worked.

Comment: WIthout two next variables, eg.: `$(SRC)` and `$(INCL)`, makefile worked

Comment: `$(CXX)=g++` worked because CXX variable has a default value which is `g++`, so after variable variable replacement, the line becomes `g++=g++` which is valid (set the g++ variable to `g++`). SRC and INCL however do not have default values, so `$(SRC)=../src` will become `=../src`, which is not quite valid Makefile syntax

Answer (score 3):

To assign value to variable write `var=...`, not `$var=...`, so, in your case,
`CXX=g++` etc.

Comment: It may come as a surprise, but `$var=...` would not usually give any error, it would just mean something other than what you probably intended for it to mean. (The question doesn't have `$var`, it has `$(var)`, and in Makefiles, the parentheses are important. `$var=...` attempts to assign to the variable whose name you get by concatenating `$v` and `ar`, where it isn't a problem if `$v` is empty.)